# Update Function Call within Python Coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a simple class for fetching URLs while periodically updating the access token using a new loop on separate thread:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from threading import Thread
from random import randint

LOOP = asyncio.get_event_loop()

NEW_LOOP = asyncio.new_event_loop()
t = Thread(target=NEW_LOOP.run_forever)
t.start()

class SOME_CLASS(object):
    def __init__(self, loop=LOOP, new_loop=NEW_LOOP):
        self.token = None
        self.loop = loop
        self.new_loop = new_loop
        self.semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(3)
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=self.loop)

        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.get_token(), self.new_loop)

    def _get_headers(self):
        headers = {
                    'x-access-token': str(self.token),
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                  }

        return headers

    async def get_token(self):
        while True:
            self.token = randint(1, 100)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)        

    async def fetch(self, url):
        async with self.semaphore:
            headers = self._get_headers()
            async with self.session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
                await response.read()
                return headers

    async def fetch_all(self):
        urls = ['https://httpbin.org/get?x={i}'for i in range(1000)]
        futures = asyncio.as_completed([self.fetch(url) for url in urls])
        for future in futures:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            headers = await future
            print(f'headers: {headers}  token: {self.token}')

    def run(self):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.fetch_all())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SOME_CLASS()
    sc.run()
```

However, I noticed that even though the `self.token` is indeed being updated every two seconds, the token stored within the `headers` stays unchanged. It seems as though `self._get_headers()` gets called well in advance and not after it acquires a semaphore:

```
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 8
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 8
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 78
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 78
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 41
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 56
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 56
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 74
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 74
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 4
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 4
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 10
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 10
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 44
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 44
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 28
headers: {'x-access-token': '8', 'content-type': 'application/json'}  token: 28
```

How do I ensure that the token actually gets updated within the `headers` right before the http request is sent off?

Comment: I don't understand why the second loop. I think you should omit it completely, and replace `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.get_token())` with a simple `loop.create_task(self.get_token())`. One of the chief _benefits_ of asyncio is not having to create threads (and deal with their weight to the OS and the various synchronization issues) for things like that.

Comment: You seem to want the `headers` local variable to automatically reflect the updated token - why? Things look like they work perfectly as they are: 1) `headers` are retrieved before the fetch using the then-current token, 2) the token is updated every two seconds, affecting new downloads. Since you are returning `headers`, you get the "old" value (in fact the value used for that download, which looks correct to me) - if you wanted to return the new current value, you could return `self._get_headers()` instead.

Comment: Actually, I want the token to be updated every 2 seconds and have that new token be used and sent in the http request with little to no delay. Right now, I am not seeing the token being updated in the header. The goal isn't so much to return the header but to ensure that the updated token is being used in the http request. Returning the header allows me to print what is being sent in the http request.

Comment: *Right now, I am not seeing the token being updated in the header.* How do you know? You're only printing the value of `header` after the download, when it's completely irrelevant (because the next download will call `_get_headers` again). You should print `header` right before the call to `session.get` - if you **then** see a stale value, you have cause for alarm.

Comment: For example, look at [this code](https://pastebin.com/ERkscGU7), which is like yours, except with aiohttp stuff replaced with a sleep. You can run it and see that the token change takes effect immediately. Also, I would suggest to get rid of unnecessary threading, as shown [here](https://pastebin.com/PYK75QWu).

Comment: Thank you! I was wrong and that did the trick

Comment: Regarding event loop in a separate thread, there might have been a misunderstanding of my suggestion from one of your previous questions. You should **never** run two event loops in parallel, that only introduces confusion. If you already have a global event loop running in the background, you can always use that one, submitting stuff to it with `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` from other threads. See [this modification](https://pastebin.com/Wz8h9ZHp) of your code for an example.

Comment: Good tip. I removed the other thread and added `get_token` back to the main thread via `create_task`. Previously, I failed to understand that `create_task` would execute immediately and thought that it still required calling `run_until_complete` (which would have prevented the event loop from returning until it completed). However, now I understand that `create_task` will execute and return immediately as long as you await the task. Then, I can run other loop-blocking tasks with `run_until_complete`. Your comments have been very helpful and I appreciate your time and patience! I learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`asyncio.sleep(2)` is to high set it 0.2, put your debug print  within  fetch and see it updated

Comment: No, this doesn't help. In the output, the value of the `x-access-token` should match the value of `token`. Notice that then value of `x-access-token` never changes even after several minutes of elapsed time. The problem is that `self._get_headers` is not getting called upon acquiring a semaphore. Instead, it seems to be called once when the future is returned.

Comment: maybe I dont get right. Within fetch the get request uses the right token, now time passes you get the response, meanwhile the token changes, you wait for fetch_all more time passes token still changes https://repl.it/repls/UnfitAptGuiltware

Comment: The sleep for the token must be longer than the fetching (in my real case, the sleep is 5 minutes and the fetch is returning results in microseconds). The `x-access-token` is taking far too long to update its value, sometimes even more than 10 seconds while the `self.token` is updating every 2 seconds. There shouldn't be a 10+ second delay. If there is, how do I get around this without changing the sleep time?

Answer (score 1):

You have a complex wrapper around a basic Python issue.  The variable `self.token` is a simple integer.  The value stored in the `headers` dictionary is a string representation of this simple integer.  When you reassign self.token to a different integer, there's no way for the program to know what other objects you would like to change at the same time.

One solution is to make `self.token` an object with an internal state.  That object can be referenced in different places in your program.  When you change its internal state, it of course takes effect immediately.  Here is a little program illustrating this, with a `class Token`. I hope you can adapt it to your more complex situation.  I don't think that the use of coroutines affects this.  I think if you assign the value of `x-access-token` to `self.token`, which is now an instance of `Token`, you are most of the way to a solution.

```
import random

# This way doesn't work
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = random.randint(1, 100)

    def change_token(self):
        self.token = random.randint(1, 100)

c = MyClass()
a = c.token
for _ in range(10):
    c.change_token()
    print(a, c.token)  # a does not change when c.token does

# This works
class Token:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.token = n

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.token)

    def set_token(self, n):
        self.token = n

class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = Token(random.randint(1, 100))

    def change_token(self):
        self.token.set_token(random.randint(1, 100))

print()
c = MyClass2()
a = c.token
for _ in range(10):
    c.change_token()
    print(a, c.token)  # a and c.token are the same object
```